# Chrome is behaving differently than Chrome on another computer

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, google-chrome, portfolio

I've been experiencing the weirdest issue. The issue occurs when rolling over items in my portfolio. When working, the image becomes darker and a 'Read More' button appears. When not working, only the darkening occurs.

Important info:

1. My site works fine in Firefox and IE on all computers I have tried
2. My site displays fine on every other Chrome I have tried, apart from my own PC and laptop (including v34 and Canary).
3. I have reset all settings, reinstalled Chrome and tested without signing in to G+
4. I am building my site in Wordpress, and am utilising the Go Portfolio plugin - this is what is driving the overlay
5. Once actually follow the link to a portfolio item, the back and forward slider links do not work, it seems that it only recognises the anchor #, not the code driving the transition. Again, this is only an issue on my PC and laptop

My site is http://www.icandesign.com.au ...still not entirely finished so please forgive the rough edges

Can anyone shed some light on this? What good is a development platform that displays incorrectly?

Thanks,
Peter R

Comment: Works for me... Is this done through javascript or css?

Comment: I'm actually receiving the back and forth slider issue under Firefox Beta as well, but the Read More button shows up fine. When something works on one browser but not on another identical browser, I usually start to suspect it has something to do with internet speed (something happening in one Javascript tag before another one before it has loaded, causing the code to break) but this is just speculation. If you copy your site to your laptop's hard drive, is the issue still there?

Comment: Hi tomysshadow, thanks for your input. I've been experiencing the issue on both localhost and live versions. I've had similar thoughts, however don't really have the skills to troubleshoot very effectively :(

PS: With regards to the slider, have you accessed an item that contains more than one piece in the slideshow?

Comment: @Max - it would appear to be jQuery - I've found a line deep in the plugin that triggers on mouseenter:

$this.find('.gw-gopf-post-content-wrap').show();

Comment: ...that was just the trigger, I still have no idea what's going on!